# There is already an object named 'name' in the database - stored procedure error - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables called `timeus` and `usdpay` in my SQL Server database. These two tables get updated every week.

I did small transformation and combined these two tables and created a new table called `fluslabor`.

I created `fluslabor` using the stored procedure shown here, and it is working:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_uslabor]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.fluslabor', N'U') IS NOT NULL
        TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[fluslabor];

    SELECT ut.employee_code
            ,ut.employee_name
            ,ut.department_desc
            ,ut.location_desc
            ,ut.hour 
            ,ut.projects_code
            ,ut.in_effective_time
            ,ut.out_effective_time
            ,ut.date
            ,ut.id  
            ,p.rate
            ,(p.rate * ut.hour ) as Labour_Cost
    INTO fluslabor
    FROM timeus ut
    LEFT JOIN usdpay p ON (TRIM(ut.id) = TRIM(p.id) AND ut.date = p.date)
    WHERE ut.projects_code NOT LIKE '0%'
END
```

Today I got new data updated in my two tables `timeus` and `usdpay`.

When I execute my stored procedure, SQL Server is throwing this error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Procedure SP_uslabor, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 38]
> There is already an object named 'fluslabor' in the database.

I need to truncate my table every time and load the new data. I checked the similar post, they said to use drop table option. I don't want to drop the table, just want to truncate and execute the procedure

Can anyone advise what is the issue here please?

Comment: Aside... _Caution: Avoid the use of the sp\_ prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name._ Ref: [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql)

Comment: Since the `fluslabor` table already exists have you considered changing your `SELECT ... INTO` statement into an `INSERT ... SELECT`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks. I will change the procedure name. I am new to stored procedures. Can you advise me on the INSERT INTO option?

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `INSERT` statement. There will certainly be examples there

Comment: If there is a chance that `fluslabor` might or might not exist at the start, an alternative fix is to change your `TRUNCATE TABLE` to a `DROP TABLE` and leave the following statement as a `SELECT...INTO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the table `fluslabor` already exists in the database. what you are trying above the insert is checking the object existence and then truncating the same

There are two possible approaches that you can try here.

1. Instead if the `TRUNCATE` do a `DROP TABLE`. But This will also remove the existing user permissions on the table if you have provided specific custom access to the table to any of the users

   `IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.fluslabor', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo].[fluslabor];`
2. The safest approach will be change the `SELECT .. INTO` statement and convert it into `INSERT INTO` like this

   `INSERT INTO fluslabor ( <List your Destination columns> ) SELECT <List your Source columns> FROM <Source Query>`

the 2nd approach will have the records loaded along with keeping all the existing permissions

Answer (score -2):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'your SP name')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE "your SP name";
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE "your SP name"

AS
BEGIN
.
.
.
.
```

try this one I guess this will help you.

Comment: Pretty sure that is not what OP is asking.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).